# How to recursively iterate through Property list in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, tree

I have a swift property list (produced by NSPropertyListSerialization) like this:

```
let plist: Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
```

where `AnyObject` can be either a String or another nested `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` or array of values Like this:

```
- key/value
- key/value
- key/dictionary
      - key/value
      - key/value
      - key/dictionary
             - key/dictionary
                    - key/value
                    - key/value
      - key/value
      - key/dictionary
             - key/value
             - key/value
```

What is the easiest way in Swift of finding out a value for any given key in the dictionary?

EDIT. I created a recursive function like this:

```
// returns value for any given key in the plist
func valueForPlistKey(key: String, parent:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> AnyObject? {

    for (akey, avalue) in parent {
        if key == akey {
            return avalue
        } else if avalue is Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let nestedVal = valueForPlistKey(key, parent: avalue as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
                return nestedVal
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, what makes things complicated is the fact that the nested object can be either dictionary or array. So unless I will need to think again...

Comment: Your answer is in the title. Create a recursive function that iterates through Dictionary and when it finds dictionary/array, it runs itself on it